# Schedule a job with at command

Tags: linux, shell-script, scheduled-tasks, bash-scripting, at

Hello I have written a script and I want to schedule it to run at a certain time with the at command. I also want to use an argument in order to pass the time I want in the script so it can be executed at a specific time. 
The script's name is displaydir and it has the following arguments:

```
./displaydir dir1 09:00 AM
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
at $2 $3
ll $1
cp ./$1/ ./dir2
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line and the script I gather that your want your directory listing to happen at nine AM. This can happen with the following command:

```
at 9am -f displaydir
```

with the following script (displaydir):

```
#!/bin/bash
ll dir1
cp ./dir1/ ./dir2
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Is there anyway to make the command line look like this: ./displaydir dir1 09:00 AM Because the hour and the directory have to be arguments

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your script as follows;

```
at ${2} <<ENDOFFILE
ls -l $1
cp $1/* $3/
exit 0
ENDOFFILE
```

Run the script at below;

```
./displaydir dir1 "09:00 AM" dir2
```

I have added "*" in the copy command and also taking destination at an argument to the script, you can add **-r to cp command** if you want to recursively copy everything in that directory